# My camera on the layout tab is stuck really far away and I am unable to zoom in

Tags: camera

after hitting 'shift + c" I was sent far away form my model and cant zoom back in.

I have tried undoing what I had done by 'ctrl + z' and has not worked
Restarting the program also didn't help

Comment: Have you tried to select an object in the outliner and use the menu command  *View > Frame Selected* (`Numpad comma`) to focus the viewport?

Comment: Unfortunately, Frame All, the command executed by shift-C, like most viewport movement doesn't go on the Undo stack so you can't undo it.  Zooming very far away usually means you have added an object that's very far from the origin, so you might want to check the outliner.  I would try @Blunder's suggestion above and also look for the outlying object